# Replacing subviews with NSBox

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, nsbox

I would like to use an NSBox *dynamicSection to replace the content of the box with a different view depending on the index selected from and NSPopUpButton control. The method below receives the NSPopUPButton as an object, and uses a case switch to dynamically set the view and title for the box.

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
IBOutlet NSTextField *dynamicTitle;
NSMutableString *title;
NSBox *dynamicSection;
NSView *Sect1_View;
NSView *Sect2_View;
NSView *Sect3a_View;
NSView *Sect3b_View;
NSView *Sect3c_View;
NSView *Sect4_View;
}
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSBox *dynamicSection;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSPopUpButton *menuOptions;

}

@implementation {

- (IBAction)menuSelected:(NSPopUpButton *)sender {

NSInteger index = [sender indexOfSelectedItem];
NSLog(@"Selected button index is %ld", index);



switch (index) {
    case 0:
        dynamicSection = [[NSBox alloc] init];
        [dynamicSection setTitle:[self returnSectionTitle:index]];
        [dynamicSection setContentView:Sect1_View];
         NSLog(@"%@",[self returnSectionTitle:index]);
        break;
    case 1:
        dynamicSection = [[NSBox alloc] init];
        [dynamicSection setTitle:[self returnSectionTitle:index]];
        [dynamicSection setContentView:Sect2_View];
        break;
    case 2:
        dynamicSection = [[NSBox alloc] init];
        [dynamicSection setTitle:[self returnSectionTitle:index]];
        [dynamicSection setContentView:Sect3a_View];
        break;
    case 3:
        dynamicSection = [[NSBox alloc] init];
        [dynamicSection setTitle:[self returnSectionTitle:index]];
        [dynamicSection setContentView:Sect3b_View];
        break;
    case 4:
        dynamicSection = [[NSBox alloc] init];
        [dynamicSection setTitle:[self returnSectionTitle:index]];
        [dynamicSection setContentView:Sect3c_View];
        break;
    case 5:
        dynamicSection = [[NSBox alloc] init];
        [dynamicSection setTitle:[self returnSectionTitle:index]];
        [dynamicSection setContentView:Sect4_View];
        break;

    default:
        break;
  }

}
```

}

It is recognizing the correct index, and printing the title to the log, however it does not correctly switch the view upon selection. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be adding the `NSBox` as a subview of the view and I cannot tell from the question where it should be added.

Other issues:

1. You need to avoid a memory leak by releasing the allocated `NSBox` once you have added it as a subview, as the view will retain it.
2. You *probably* don't need to hold `dynamicSection` as an ivar of the class.
3. You have too much repeated code:

Do this before the `switch`:

```
dynamicSection = [[NSBox alloc] init];
[dynamicSection setTitle:[self returnSectionTitle:index]];
```

and add the view after the `switch`:

```
[someView addSubview:dynamicSection];
[dynamicSection release];
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have made the changes before and after the switch statement. Do I need to create a custom view inside the NSBox as a subview?

Comment: No, you need to add the `NSBox` **to** a view.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example? I currently positioned the NSBox inside the main view in Nib associated with the AppDelegate.

Comment: Have you got Aaron Hillegass's `Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X - 4ed`?  Chapter 31 presents a view swapping example that uses an `NSBox`.

Comment: Ok great, thanks. I just found a separate example which instantiates the view controller subclass:  Sect1 = [[Sect1_View alloc] initWithNibName:@"Sect1_View" bundle:nil];
            [dynamicSection setContentView:Sect1.view];
            [dynamicSection release];